# Browse button for FTP

Tags: java, button, ftp, jfilechooser

I am new to java and trying to learn. Right now I am trying to write a download/upload manager program. I want to make a browse button for FTP so user can select from there which file to download. I can download it writing its directory, manually. Is there a way to do this using **JFileChooser** or with a similar class? I don't want to use a plugin since I want to write it myself. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "I don't want to use a plugin since I want to write it myself". Unless you want to write the complete [FTP Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP_client) yourself, consider using [ftp4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/).

`JFileChooser` is to choose local file(s). Or provide your own `FileSystemView` with `ftp4j` backend and use it to choose files on the remote server for download.

Short answer: Just use ftp4j to browse files over FTP.